# Can I find a bound to show that $\lvert x-y\rvert ^{2}\geq c\lvert \lvert x\rvert ^2-\lvert y\rvert^2\rvert $

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality, convergence-divergence

Can I find a constant $c$ to show that $\lvert x-y\rvert ^{2}\geq c\lvert \lvert x\rvert ^2-\lvert y\rvert^2\rvert $ for $x,y\in \mathbb R\; (*)$.

Background to my question:

In a proof I saw the use of the fact that if $X_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{2}}X$ then it follows $(X_{n})^{2}\xrightarrow{L^{1}}X^2$. Now I assume that this means an inequality of the form $(*)$ must hold, but I am struggling to prove it. Any ideas?

EDIT: So if that inequality $(*)$ is not possible, then how does $X_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{2}}X$ imply $(X_{n})^{2}\xrightarrow{L^{1}}X^2$?

Answer (score 1):

We wish to prove:

$$|x-y|^{2}\geq c|x^2-y^2|$$

$$|x-y|^{2}\geq c|x-y||x+y|$$

Assuming $x\neq y$, because the inequality is trivially true if $x=y$:

$$|x-y|\geq c|x + y|$$

Assuming $x\neq -y$, as the inequality is again trivial if this is true:

$$c\leq\left|\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right|$$

However, the RHS can get arbitrarily close to $0$ (though it is always positive) as $x$ approaches $y$. Thus $c\leq 0$, the largest possible $c$ is $\boxed{0}$.

Comment: Why would  it then hold that $X_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{2}}X$ implies $(X_{n})^{2}\xrightarrow{L^{1}}X^{2}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If $c \leq 0$, the LHS will automatically be non-negative and the RHS will automatically be non-positive.  Therefore, the problem reduces to assuming that $c$ is required to be $> 0.$

Without Loss of Generality, $x > y > 0.$

Then, LHS $= (x-y)(x-y)$ and RHS $= c(x-y)(x+y).$

Therefore, the problem reduces to **trying to show** that you can find a scalar $c> 0$ such that regardless of the values of $x,y$,  
$$(x-y) \geq c(x+y) \implies \frac{x-y}{x+y} \geq c.\tag 1$$

With $x,y$ variables constrained only by $x > y > 0$, then regardless of how small $c$ is chosen to be, you can always find values for $x,y$ such that inequality (1) above does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

**Such a strictly positive constant can't exist**

Take $x_n = n+1= y_n+1$. Following inequality would have to hold for all $n \in \mathbb N$
$$1=\lvert x_n-y_n\rvert ^{2}\geq c \left(2n+1\right)=\lvert \lvert x_n\rvert ^2-\lvert y_n\rvert^2\rvert$$

which is not possible.

Comment: Just a minor thing, $c\leq 0$ works.

Comment: @JoshuaWang You're right, though $c \lt 0$ would have no interest vs the question!